# how to add google map as a ui component in magento 2

Tags: google-maps, magento, magento2

i need to display a coordinates field , coming from database, currently am displaying it as an input like this:

[image]

i need to display it as map like this:

[image]

i googled a LOT and lot of answers on how to load the map using requireJS , but non is working with Magento 2.1..

currently am at this stage:

```
requirejs.config({
    paths: {
        googlemaps: 'googlemaps',
        async: 'requirejs-plugins/src/async'
    },
  googlemaps: {
    params: {
      key: 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxx'
    }
  }
});

define([
  'Magento_Ui/js/form/element/abstract',
  'jquery',
  'googlemaps!'
],function(Abstract,$,gmaps) {
    return Abstract.extend({

        initialize: function () {
            return this._super();
        },

        initMap: function() {
          console.log(this.value());
          console.log("-------------");
          var uluru = {lat: -25.363, lng: 131.044};
          var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
            zoom: 4,
            center: uluru
          });
          var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: uluru,
            map: map
          });
        },

    });
});
```

now , question is how to call the initMap function after page is loaded ?

***help pleaaaaase***

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because Stack Overflow is a [programming-related](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) Q&A site. Your question is not about programming. Perhaps you should post it on http://magento.stackexchange.com instead?

Comment: this question is very about programming !  it about how to create/code the UI component

Comment: Don't ask us to write code for you. You need to come here with your code and then we can help you fix whatever is wrong with it.

Comment: no one is asking you to code anything, if you dont want to help, then please just ignore the question